# Dead in the water over a technicality?

Tags: discussion

I've posed a question applying the word 'adopted' [here](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1100/the-art-of-war-by-sun-tzu-when-and-where-it-was-adopted-first-outside-of-chin).

It quickly got put on hold because this word was decided to be ambiguous.
I corrected it with what I regard a trivial update.
Now the question is reopened but also dead in the water.

All in all this does not raise my expectations of this brand new site. Is it loosing momentum already? Do I want to put effort into a process apparently so fragile?

Where DO we want to go?

P.S. SO expecting to be slammed now.

*Edit:* Indeed being slammed. Hardly ever being glad to be. But glad this time, indeed. Wished I'd be able to accept all answers, they are all GOOD.

Comment: Define "dead in the water". Do you mean that there's little activity on the question?

Comment: It could just be that nobody knows the answer now.

Comment: @fi12, thanks for supporting my case. Some questioning helps, other questioning... blocks. Dead in the water, to spell it out, means that I no longer expect any result due to ageing while the mod action was being played out.

Comment: I think it is only that no one has the answer as Mith said. What do you mean that we are losing momentum?

Comment: I'll fetch a book from my library and post an answer (hopefully) on 2 February

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give it a little time.

The question is new, and not that easy to answer. Anyone who wants to answer it properly will have to do some history research, to back up their claims. I'm not sure how much data is available on the spread of the Sun Tzu beyond China.
Also, it's weekend - Stack Exchange is often a little slower during the weekend.

Once we go public beta, there will be plenty more eyes on this question.

It's still possible that the question will end up with a Tumbleweed badge, but right at the moment, I wouldn't be too worried about that.

Comment: Thanks. Would *love* to be on the wrong foot here.

Comment: Slightly tangential, but public beta might not bring as much (participating) traffic as you'd expect/hope; take a look at [What is the typical growth pattern of a new beta site in the first few weeks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227007/what-is-the-typical-growth-pattern-of-a-new-beta-site-in-the-first-few-weeks). My experience on the new [Internet of Things](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) site is that you don't get all that many new visitors straight away in public beta; it's a case of slowly building traffic instead.

Answer (score 9):

### Patience, my young padawan.

"Dead in the water"? Really? It's been less than a day since your question was reopened, and on a Sunday too - always one of the quietest days of the Stack Exchange week. Take a look at [all these unanswered questions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes) - you're in good company.

Remember, not everyone knows about every possible work of literature - and those who do know about a specific work aren't online all the time. Just wait; I'm sure your question will be answered eventually, hopefully with something that makes it worth the wait. Better to get a good answer after several days than a poor one right away.

Comment: Aha! Finally, you're telling that to *somebody else* :)

Comment: @Mithrandir We've all been waiting for this day...

Comment: My point that we don't have to worry about the site being too inactive is supported by *this answer* getting **four upvotes in less than a minute**.

Comment: It's even more supported by the fact that *this question* received 3 answers with several upvotes and comments each, within a mere 25 minutes of this meta question being asked.

Comment: Thanks for your sage advice, most respectable teacher. Seeing this activity, and so much of it, puts me to shame. __Its alive!__

Comment: BTW 'unanswered' is one shorter now :-)

Answer (score 7):

Don't worry about it as of now; we may just simply lack the history expertise to answer the question. As Mithrandir points out, it could be simply that no one knows the answer. Once we reach public beta, we'll receive many more visitors, some of whom may be able to provide answers to the question. If you really want an answer though, the best way to do it is to keep editing your question to make it as clear as possible, which will push it to the front page, and perhaps add a bounty once we reach the public beta stage.

Provided our site activity is normal, we should reach the public beta stage in just a few days.

Comment: Hoping right along with you. However my experience is that the window where questions get any activity is narrow. Cheers,

Comment: @Bookeater This question should experience the *meta effect* either way (the increase in attention to a question that occurs when you post about it on meta.)

Comment: It seems it already did. But the reason I posted this meta is because it kept rotating in my mind. This site has such potential.